# How to create a function local mutable variable in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

Consider the following hypothetical nonsensical ClojureScript function:

```
(defn tmp [] 
  (def p 0)
  (set! p (inc p))
  (set! p (inc p))
  (set! p (inc p)))
```

Repeatedly executing this function in a REPL results in

```
3
6
9
etc.
```

Is it possible to create a mutable variable which is local to the function, such that the output would have been

```
3
3
3
etc.
```

in the case of repeated exection of (tmp)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let` lets you assign variables limited to it's scope:

```
(defn tmp[]
  (let [p 0]
    ...))
```

Now, clojurescript makes use of immutable data. That means everything is basically a constant, and once you set a value of `p`, there is no changing it. There are two ways you can get around this:

### Use more local variables

```
(defn tmp[]
  (let [a 0
        b (inc a)
        c (inc b)
        d (inc c)]
    ...))
```

### Use an `atom`

Atoms are somewhat different from other data structures in clojurescript and allow control of their state. Basically, you can see them as a reference to your value.

When creating an atom, you pass the initial value as its argument. You can access an atoms value by adding `@` in front of the variable, which is actually a macro for `(deref my-var)`.

You can change the value of an atom using `swap!` and `reset!` functions. Find out more about them in the [cljs cheatsheet](http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/).

```
(defn tmp[]
  (let [p (atom 0)]
    (reset! p (inc @p))
    (reset! p (inc @p))
    (reset! p (inc @p))))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this of course, but I got this error:
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Can't set! local var or non-mutable field at line 3 <cljs repl> - I added 'mutable' to the title but the term was in the question. - Who upvotes an answer which is not correct?

Comment: I thought you might be aware of that since you described your code as partly non-sense. Anyway, I updated my answer to cover all of it.

Comment: Thanks, the addition of more local variables would not work in the case I have at hand. A local atom would do the job though, I will try that solution right away.

Comment: wow really! what a silly language. local atom worked but seems kind of weird. is that an expensive operation by using an atom? the equivalent of this `String filename = null; try { possibly set filename } finally { if (filename != null) new File(filename).delete() }` is quite hard to do in clojure

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza why would you "possibly set filename"? Usually there are ways in Clojure to do things without using mutable variables like the `String filename`. And if you really need one you can use an atom. Atom performance is fine. It uses [Java code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java) to manage shared, synchronous, independent state (e.g., you don't have to do to locking yourself when working with concurrent code).